# VBA vlookup to copy specific columns from multiple sheets to master sheet

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am using Excel to produce reports for a billing system and I would like to use VBA to simplify the process of updating the excel. What I want to do is to use vlookup function to reflect columns (G:AI) from respective Named worksheets back to mastersheet. All sheets starts from row 4. (Row 3 is header)

So I'll further simplify the process as such:

VLOOKUP VBA (When changes made in the Named worksheets)
1. To enable Vlookup function in column (G:AI) in Mastersheet from Named worksheets ("John", "Charlie", "George") 
2. As Mastersheet is a mixed data of John, Charlie and George, to input Vlookup formulas across column (G:AI) accordingly, then till last row of Mastersheet
3. My vlookup range will be from Named worksheets (John, Charlie, George), range (A1:AI) starting from column 7, row 4 till the end of the data.

```
ws1.Cells(r, c).Value = Application.VLookup(ws1.Cells(r, 1).Value, wsNames.Range("A1:AI500"), colnum, False)
```

Here are the codes I have so far. It's all I worked out (with help) as of now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My issue is, when running the code, vlookup values for ws11 is in the right place. However, vlookup values for ws12 and ws13 are shifted towards further left of the worksheet. For example, 
while vlookup values for ws11 is in columns (A:AI) - the right columns
vlookup values for ws12 is in columns (AP:BR) - 7 columns from column AI and 
vlookup values for ws13 is in columns (BY:DA) - 7 columns from column BR
Is there a line of code that I can insert to fix this?

```
Sub green_update()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws11 As Worksheet, ws12 As Worksheet, ws13 As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws11 = wb.Sheets("Sheet11")
Set ws12 = wb.Sheets("Sheet12")
Set ws13 = wb.Sheets("Sheet13")


Dim colNo As Long, ARowNo as Long
Dim for_col As Long, i As Long, r As Long, c As Long, colnum As Long
r = 4: c = 7: colnum = 7

Dim wsNames As Variant
For Each wsNames In Sheets(Array("sheet11", "sheet12", "sheet13"))

colNo = wsNames.Cells("4", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 For for_col = 1 To colNo

ARowNo = wsNames.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    For i = 1 To ARowNo
    ws1.Cells(r, c).Value = Application.VLookup(ws1.Cells(r, 1).Value, wsNames.Range("A1:AI500"), colnum, False)
    If IsError(ws1.Cells(r, c).Value) Then
    ws1.Cells(r, c).Value = 0
    End If
    r = r + 1

    Next

 r = 4
 colnum = colnum + 1
 c = c + 1

Next

colnum = 7 

  Next wsNames

End Sub
```

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: I'm making an assumption that this is falling over due to colnum not being set before it is used in the vlookup

Comment: @SJR I have edited the question for better understanding. My apologies for the delay

Comment: @smithy7876 I think the colnum is okay cause I needed it to run in different columns as it run. Now it's the alignment of the vlookup values in ws12 and ws13 respectively that has an issue. Thank you. :)

Comment: At the moment you have hard-coded `wsNames.Range("A1:AI500")`. Are you saying that this only applies to the first sheet in your loop and that for each of the others it should be shifted right as you have indicated?

Comment: @SJR I hardcoded the range A1:AI500 because I can't figure out a way to make it run till the end row. And no, it should apply to all sheets. The range across all sheets should be from column A:AI until the last row.

Comment: `ARowNo` looks like it should give you the last row. based on your previous answer, I'm slightly confused by your reference "the right columns vlookup values for ws12 is in columns (AP:BR) - 7 columns from column AI and vlookup values for ws13 is in columns (BY:DA) - 7 columns from column BR"? Can you clarify please?

Comment: @SJR Sorry. I think because the code runs by worksheet, the first worksheet (ws11) runs perfectly whereby the vlookup values are at columns A:AI. When the code runs for the subsequent worksheets (ws12 & ws13), instead of starting from column A, it started at column AI(the end of ws11) for ws12 and column BS for ws13 (the end of ws12). I think the entire code shifted so maybe the solution is to ensure that when working on the ws12 and ws13, it starts from column A?

Comment: Have you posted all of your code? I can't see that the variable `for_col` is used in the loop.

Comment: @SJR Yes, I've posted all of my codes. I've referenced from another site for the "for_col" variable. My assumption is that "for column 1". Please do change it if it's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly can't see what can be causing the problem you describe based on the code posted. There is nothing substantially different in the code below - I have tidied up a couple of the loops and incorporated the last row variable. Let me know how you get on.

```
Sub green_update()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim colNo As Long, ARowNo As Long
Dim for_col As Long, i As Long, r As Long, c As Long, colnum As Long

r = 4: c = 7: colnum = 7

Dim wsNames As Variant

For Each wsNames In Sheets(Array("sheet11", "sheet12", "sheet13"))
    colNo = wsNames.Cells("4", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ARowNo = wsNames.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For for_col = 1 To colNo
        For i = 1 To ARowNo
            ws1.Cells(r, c).Value = Application.VLookup(ws1.Cells(r, 1).Value, wsNames.Range("A1:AI" & ARowNo), colnum, False)
            If IsError(ws1.Cells(r, c).Value) Then
                ws1.Cells(r, c).Value = 0
            End If
            r = r + 1
        Next i
        r = 4
        colnum = colnum + 1
        c = c + 1
    Next for_col
    colnum = 7
Next wsNames

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried the code and what happened is it only showing vlookup values from one sheet. I've played around with the code "For Each wsNames In Sheets(Array("sheet11", "sheet12", "sheet13"))" and rearranged the sequence. So when the run sheets(Array("sheet11","sheet12","sheet13"), only vlookup value of "sheet13" is shown. When run sheets(Array("sheet13","sheet12","sheet11"), vlookup value of "sheet11" is shown. They seem to take only the last sheet. But when  run sheets(Array("sheet11","sheet13","sheet12"), vlookup value shown is the sheet in the middle. "sheet12" value doesn't show.

Comment: I did something remarkably silly before so have amended code which should rectify the problems above, but not sure about your original question.

Comment: Can you describe how you expect your results to appear? You do a bunch of lookups on sheet11, then where should the next sheet's results appear - directly below? And what is the value of `colNo` for each sheet?

Comment: I want the all the results from ws11-13 to appear on sheet1 in column G:AI. After I have done the looksups on sheet 11, ideally looksups for sheet12 and sheet13 should appear within the same column range. The amended code puts sheet11 vlookup values in the right spot (column G:AI) but not for sheet12 (in column BY:DA) and sheet13 (vlookup value didnt copy) colNo should be the same across all worksheets as rows starts from 4. colNum starts from 7(column"G") to end of sheet, but in this case should be 35 (column"AI").

Comment: yups! Thank you so much!